# Cannot format list of double into type of Date

Tags: date, r

```
>library(eeptools)
>library(lubridate)

> a = c("2019-06-09", "2006-05-04")

> is.Date(a)
[1] FALSE
> 
> as.Date(a, "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2019-06-09" "2006-05-04"
>
> typeof(a)
[1] "character"
> 
> is.Date(a)
[1] FALSE
> 
> class(a)
[1] "character"
```

I was trying to turn a list of character into Date but it seems that as.Date() does not work out for some reasons. Could anyone tell me where I did wrong and how I should do to turn the type of list into Date.

Comment: You never assign first line to any object. You just output the conversion.

Comment: You need to assign the result: `a <- as.Date(a, "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: Thank you so much! @sindri_baldur

Answer (score -1):

If you try to convert just one element of a list of characters into a date, the list won't accept it. You have to assign the same data type to the whole list. Say I create a list:

```
Dataset$dob <- c("1986-10-17", "1987-10-17")
```

Now I can convert it to date like so:

```
Dataset$dob <- as.Date(Dataset$dob)
> class(Dataset$dob[1])
[1] "Date"
```

Or for whatever reason if you only want to convert the first element to date:

```
dob1 <- as.Date(Dataset$dob[1])
> class(dob1)
[1] "Date"
```

Also, if you just wanted to test your code, the logic would be

```
> is.Date(as.Date(Dataset$dob[1]))
[1] TRUE
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried your method but it does not give me the same output.